# JQuery - No Conflict or closure

Tags: jquery

I am writing an application at the moment that uses jquery.  It fits in to an existing application that uses prototype so obviously I cant use the dollar sign straight away.

I have been using noconflict to get around this but couldnt I just wrap my whole script inside a closure passing in jquery as in:

```
(function( $ ){

})( jQuery );
```

This seems to work but I am wondering if there are any consequences to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine, since your passing jQuery into your closure as the jQuery object itself.

The noConflict should still be specified though - otherwise the jQuery object could take control of the dollar sign. Calling noConflict passes the dollar sign back to anything that is already using it.

The documentation suggests this too:

```
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use both :

```
(function( $ ){

})( jQuery.noConflict() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This Will work Like a charm as long as you don't need to access the variables that are defined inside the block.

Jquery plugins are usually coded using this exact shielding construct.

Use It instead of noConflict if you can because noConflict forces you to pay a lot more attention to the script ordering in your page.

You will need to load prototype after jquery so that It can take ownership of the $ sign.

Answer (score 0):

[noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) resets all the variables that jQuery has set with their original values. Instead of saying:

```
$(document).ready()
```

you just say

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```